# How to retrieve specific data from Firebase Database Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an app using the Realtime Database and Kotlin. How can I display the username from my database? The username is stored using a User data class. Now I can only display the UID and email when the user successfully logs in. Could you please help me to solve the issue?

Here is my loginActivity.kt

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener{
        when{
            TextUtils.isEmpty(et_login_email.text.toString().trim{it <=' '}) -> {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            TextUtils.isEmpty(et_login_password.text.toString().trim{it <=' '}) -> {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else ->{
                val email:String = et_login_email.text.toString().trim{it <=' '}
                val password:String = et_login_password.text.toString().trim{it <=' '}


                //new
                val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
                val uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid)
                uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        val snapshot = task.result
                        val email = snapshot?.child("email")?.getValue(String::class.java)
                        val username = snapshot?.child("username")?.getValue(String::class.java)
                        Log.d("TAG", "email: $email\nusername: $username")
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG", task.exception!!.message!!) //Don't ignore potential errors!
                    }
                }

                //Log-in using FirebaseAuth
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener { task ->

                        if(task.isSuccessful){
                            Toast.makeText(this,"You are logged successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity,HomeActivity::class.java)
                            intent.flags= Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                            intent.putExtra("user_id", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
                            intent.putExtra("user_name", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.displayName)
                            intent.putExtra("email_id",email)
                            startActivity(intent)
                            finish()

                        }else {
                            //If the login is not successful then show error message.
                            Toast.makeText(this,task.exception!!.message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    ForgotPassword.setOnClickListener{
        startActivity(Intent(this@LoginActivity,ForgotPasswordActivity::class.java))
    }

    textViewCreate.setOnClickListener{
        val intent= Intent(this,RegisterActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

}
```

}

User Data Class

```
data class User(
val username: String? = null,
val email:String? = null,
val phoneNum:String? = null,
val password:String? = null){
```

}

[image: database structure]

SettingFragment.kt

```
class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(com.example.login.R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false)

    view.addLocation.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(requireContext(), LocationActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }


    val userId = requireActivity().intent.getStringExtra("user_id")
    val emailId = requireActivity().intent.getStringExtra("email_id")


    view.tv_user_id.text = "UserId :: $userId"
    view.tv_email_id.text = "Email ID :: $emailId"

    return view
}
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Hi sir, I already edit my question and upload the database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Firebase authentication with user and password, the `displayName` property inside the [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object is null. To be able to read the data that corresponds to the signed-in user, you need to read the details from the database. So please use the following lines of code:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid)
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        val snapshot = task.result
        val email = snapshot.child("email").getValue(String::class.java)
        val username = snapshot.child("username").getValue(String::class.java)
        Log.d("TAG", "email: $email\nusername: $username")
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", task.exception!!.message!!) //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
}
```

And for Java users:

```
FirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid);
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            String email = snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
            String username = snapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", "email: " + email + "\nusername: " + username);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will me:

```
email: simon123@gmail.com
username: simon
```

Comment: Sorry sir, it still displays null answer

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Please check my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Is that need to add one more or replace the FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)? I am using kotlin, but I still get the null answer.

Comment: This code should **not** replace any existing code. Should be added in addition to what you already have. What does `Log.d("TAG", "email: " + email + "\nusername: " + username);` print in the logcat?

Comment: it can display the username, but not the right user account

Comment: This code will always display the email and user name of the authenticated user. Do you want to display another one? I'm not sure I understand you.

Comment: Hi sir, I have updated my code. Now the program comes out with an error which is java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting NullPointerException? Are you sure you are authenticated before using that code?

Comment: at this line (val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid) .I am sure can authenticated before using that code.

Comment: I'm afraid you're not since that line produces a NullPointerException. Most likely `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser` return null, right? Check against nullity before actually using it.